# Need help turning a C function into an Objective C method

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa, oop

I have a function written in C that is rather large and currently is only running in the main() function of a C file while I have been using to test it out. Here is it's declaration

```
void getData(const char* encodedBuffer, int user);
```

If you would like to see the contents of getData [Here](http://pastebin.com/EFSTy2N3/) is the pastebin for it.

As of now I'm just passing in encodedBuffer which I will have a global variable that is getting updated by the `getData` function.

I would like to know what the proper way is to turn a C based function like this into a Objective-C protocol method. Right now I'm setting it up like this

iDriver.h (my interface/protocol)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol iDriver <NSObject>
-(void)getData;
-(void)cancel;

@end
```

DriverOne.h (Class that actually implements the protocol method)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "iDriver.h"

@interface DriverOne : NSObject <iDriver>

@end
```

DriverOne.m

```
#import "DriverOne.h"

@implementation DriverOne

enum Status getData(char* encodedBuffer, int user)
{
    // Copy C code which I showed in the link earlier
    // to above into this method. I will want it to return a status
    // and populate a global variable with the data.
}
```

My thought is that I shouldn't really run into any issues doing this since Objective-C is a superset of C but just copying the C code into a method like that be problematic?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19366134/what-does-objective-c-is-a-superset-of-c-more-strictly-than-c-mean-exactly I don't think you should run into any problems, but then again, trying won't hurt.

Comment: Why the need for the protocol? Why not just have `getData` and `cancel` methods on `DriverOne`?

Comment: @TravisGriggs because not to far from now I will be having to add another driver which will also be using getData. I will also be changing getData to return a struct called status of type enum. I really just figured it would be best to have an interface to work with but I'm new to both C and Obj-C so I could be wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When porting a C function to an ObjC method, it's just a tweak to the signature. In your case, you'll change:

```
enum Status getData(char* encodedBuffer, int user)
```

to something like:

```
- (enum Status) getData: (char*) encodedBuffer user: (int) user
```

Objective C methods are always denoted with a `-` at the beginning (class methods start with a `+`). If you want to specify the type, you put in parens (otherwise it's assumed to be type `id` which is generic for "object"). And you have to keywordize your function name. One keyword for each argument.

Then just like C, you can just copy paste that line into your header file:

```
@protocol iDriver <NSObject>
- (enum Status) getData: (char*) encodedBuffer user: (int) user;
@end
```

After that just copy the guts inside the method.

It's not clear how familiar you are with the ideas behind OO and instances, but using it might look something like:

```
DriverOne *driverOneObject = [[DriverOne alloc] init];
char *buffer = malloc(YOUR_BUFFER_SIZE);
enumStatus status = [driverObject getData: buffer user: SomeUserThing];
```

Coming full circle, is there a reason you want this to be reified (turned into objects)? I'm all for lots of objects myself, but one of the features of ObjectiveC, is that it IS a superset of C. You can just use your function as is from your C prototype. You don't have to wrap it up in an ObjectiveC object, unless you see an advantage to doing so.

Comment: Thanks! So then copying and pasting what would normally be the guts of the old C getData would then work just the same as it would in a C file minus being called in main()? So that it can essentially be called from another class as long as the DriverOne.h is included in that file?

Comment: I normally work in C# so it just feels normal to create the objects I guess. I actually have this same driver written in C# and am just trying to convert to Obj-C in order to use it on Mac, but I have been getting confused with the syntax.